# Joomla/Mootools capturing order of Sortables

Tags: forms, joomla, mootools, submit, sortables

I am trying to sort a list of database entries and then update the database with the new order in Joomla.

So far I've got mootools `Sortables` list with every `<li>` having two hidden `<input>` to track the entry's id and order. At the moment the order variable does not change and just reflects the original order.

I was hoping to capture the submit event and change the order variables to what they should now be and then send the request on, however I have no idea how to do this...

I have:

```
<li style="float:left">
    <input type="hidden" name="o<?php echo $row->order; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="i<?php echo $row->order; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->lotid; ?>" />
    Lot <?php echo $row->lot_name; ?><br />
    <?php echo $row->address; ?>
</li>
```

And:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    new Sortables('#order-grid', {opacity: 0.7});

    form = document.id('adminForm');
    list = document.id('order-grid');

    form.addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        var sortOrder = [];

        list.getElements('li').each(function(li) {
            sortOrder.push(li.retrieve... //Stuck!
        });
    });
});
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the doc pages are your friend. http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Sortables

first off, i'd say save a reference.

```
var sortables = new Sortables(options)
```

then you can use the `sortables.serialize()` method to retrieve the new order. by default, serialization will return the element ids - but it takes an argument that is a function - so you can return whatever you like.

eg. to get an array of the new sort order, simply do

```
var newOrder = sortables.serialize(function(el, index) {
    return el.get('data-id'); // or el.retrieve('id'); if you have one. 
});
```

Finally, no need to do it on the submit event - you can just do something like:

```
var orderField = document.id("i_something_order");
new Sortables('#order-grid', {
    onComplete: function() {
        orderField.set('value', this.serialize(function(el) {
            el.retrieve('id');
        }).join(','));
    }
});
```

note that `retrieve` implies you have used `store` beforehand. if it's a DOM attribute you are after, just do `el.get('data-id')` or whatever it is as suggested

Comment: Thanks for reply, how would I get name and value from my inputs? That's my main problem, so then I can change those values.

Comment: Thanks added a function onComplete that looped through the inputs and resets their order. Works. Just a mention that I had read the man.